# cannot reproduce bulbs/py2neo in python to create edges (relationships)

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, bulbs

I am trying to sequentially insert vertices and edges in neo4j using python. The existing nodes aren't recognised as such when I add edges. Whether I use py2neo or bulbs I got a similar error message.

Note I am working with:
linux64
python2.7
bulbs0.3
py2neo1.5
neo4j-community1.8.2

With bulbs:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.vertices.create(name="James")
>>> g.vertices.create(name="Julie")
>>> g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9ba24256218d> in <module>()
----> 1 g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie)

NameError: name 'james' is not defined
```

With py2neo

```
from py2neo import neo4j
graph=neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
node=graph.create({"name":'James'},{'name':'Julie'})
rel=graph.create((james,"knows",julie))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-591f826cfd05> in <module>()
      2 graph=neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
      3 node=graph.create({"name":'James'},{'name':'Julie'})
----> 4 rel=graph.create((james,"knows",julie))

NameError: name 'james' is not defined
```

Moreover I got the same error with `bulbs` if I use `rexster` instead of `neo4j`, i.e.

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.vertices.create(name="James")
>>> g.vertices.create(name="Julie")
>>> g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2cfb5faa42d1> in <module>()
      3 g.vertices.create(name="James")
      4 g.vertices.create(name="Julie")
----> 5 g.edges.create((james, "knows", julie))

NameError: name 'james' is not defined
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application variables `james` and `julie` won't automatically be created simply by creating nodes with a similar `name` property. You haven't shared any of your py2neo code and I'm not familiar with bulbs but within py2neo you will need to do something like:

```
from py2neo import neo4j
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
james, julie = graph_db.create(node(name="James"), node(name="Julie"))
graph_db.create(rel(james, "KNOWS", julie))
```

You could of course instead create both nodes and relationship in the same statement (and batch) if you preferred:

```
from py2neo import neo4j
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
james, julie, friendship = graph_db.create(
    node(name="James"), node(name="Julie"), rel(0, "KNOWS", 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `james` or `julie` vars on your create statements.

Here's the proper code:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> james = g.vertices.create(name="James")
>>> julie = g.vertices.create(name="Julie")
>>> g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie)
```

See the [Bulbs Quickstart](http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/#create-vertices-and-edges) for more examples.